# How to disable auto-inserted 'inline' keyword in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I love the **Move definition location** refactoring feature of Visual Studio 2015 except one thing.
It automatically insert `inline` keyword ahead of function definition.
So I always had to remove them by my self.

It is like this.

### Before refactoring.

```
class GameLoop
{
public:
    void drawGame() {

    }
};
```

### After refactoring(Move definition location)

```
//GameLoop.h
class GameLoop
{
public:
    void drawGame();
};
//GameLoop.cpp
inline void GameLoop::drawGame() {

}
```

Anybody knows how to disable this auto `inline` keyword?

Thanks.

---

For whom doesn't know where is this feature.

1. Move cursor on the method you want refactor
2. [Edit]->[Refactor]->[Move Definition Location]

or

2. Press **Ctrl+.** shortcut and select **Move Definition Location**

Comment: Why would you remove them? Typically everything should be marked as inline to give compiler a bit more freedom to optimize. Note that inline does not necessary mean that code will be inlined, it's just a suggestion for compiler (unlike more strict directives, such as __forceinline).

Comment: @dodo951 Because **inlined** definition of member function in CPP file gives me a link error... If the definition is in the header, everything is ok.

Comment: My apologies for a misleading answer, but my point was to keep everything inlined either by leaving function definition in class body, or by writing it in a header with "inline" keyword present. Basically i suggest to go with SKU (single compilation unit) technique.

Comment: The code snippet shows the definition moved to a header file, not to a .cpp file. This should not cause a linker error.

Answer (score 3):

According to
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/refactoring/move-definition-location?view=msvc-140
it seeems as if its function is to move from source to header file, not vice versa.

However, the inline keyword for non-template functions in the source file - as you describe - is semantically correct, since the function definition within the class definition is implicitly inline, but it is not really a desirable behavior.
I agree.
I guess you could post this as an improvement issue to the VS devs.

On a sidenote, what I observed for **template functions** was (in VS2019):

1. Move function definition from within the class body to outside the class body in the header file.
2. Move function definition back from outside the class body to inside.
3. back and forth in header file.

This behavior has much more merit in my opinion.